# Language Module Error - Internal Compiler Error. Error Code = 0000000d . (MS Dynamics NAV)

Tags: compiler-errors, navision, dynamics-nav

When i do import a language module, I get this error on almost all different type of objects, So i just unmark them.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Dynamics NAV Development Environment
---------------------------
Internal Compiler Error. Error Code = 0000000d .


---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Do anyone know the cause of this error and how to overcome it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening when you try to import the language module for an object which cannot be compiled. 
Compile all object, rectify the problems and try again.

Cheers!

Comment: no problem! happy to help (unfortunately this is the NAV world : you need to know if an error message means something very different :-\ )